# Yii UserIdentity changed for email login and issues with Admin

Tags: email, authentication, yii, admin

I have changed the Yii UserIdentity class to accept Email from Database as login. Now the problem is that - I am unable to configure this for Admin. Here is my changed code

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
            $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
            if($user === NULL)
            {
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            }
            else
            {
                    if($user->password !== $user->encrypt($this->password))
                    {
                            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            $this->_id = $user->id;
                            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
                    }

            }
            return !$this->errorCode;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
            return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

which works fine for all users. Now, How do I accept for Admin login?
So, I changed my code slightly as below for Admin access, but it does not work for admin. Any help in this regard, will be highly appreciated.

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate()
    {
            $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$this->username));
            if($user === NULL)
            {
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
            }
            else
            {
                    if($user->password !== $user->encrypt($this->password))
                    {
                            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            if($user->email == 'example@example.com')
                                    $user->id = 'admin';
                            $this->_id = $user->id;
                            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
                    }

            }
            return !$this->errorCode;
    }
    public function getId()
    {
            return $this->_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to log ``$user->email`` value. Also,the better solution use roles (ex. ADMIN_ROLE, USER_ROLE) instead hardcoded ``$user->email == 'example@example.com'``.

Comment: It is already hardcoded in the second piece of code. Also Role Based Access is also present in the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be

```
$user->id = 'admin';
```

Where you're attempting to set the value of the primary key to a string. I could be wrong. You could try this:

```
if($user->email === 'example@example.com') {
    Yii::app()->user->setState('role','admin');
}
$this->_id = $user->id;
```

And then verify an admin in your controllers as an expression -

```
'expression'=>'Yii::app()->getState("role") == "admin"'
```

**edit**

You should add a value to the users table that establishes access levels. Then once the password is verified just put a switch statement in there, ex

```
switch($user->type) {
    case 'admin':
        # do this
    break;
    case 'user':
        # do that
    break;
 }
```